# How to override default font weights in Bootstrap 5.3 using css stylesheet

Tags: html, css, overriding, bootstrap-5

***I want my h1 heading to be a Montserrat black with font weight 900.*** However on inspecting my website in google developer tools I see that **my css code is being overridden by the bootstrap link**. Also i can't delete the bootstrap link or my navbar won't work.

How to override the default bootstrap font weight 500 to get a font weight of 900 for my h1?

> I tried a solution via including sass file in CSS however that code
> works only for bootstrap 4 and not on bootstrap 5.3 version.

There are override css code solutions for bootstrap 4 not on bootstrap 5.3 dictionary.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5; /* overridden to 1.2 */
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 900; /* overridden to 500 */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1>Montserrat black 900 font weight</h1>
```

Comment: FYI, you were using incorrect comment syntax in your CSS. That could be a problem.

Comment: incorrect comment syntax in my CSS?? it's not a syntax problem, i used the correct comment syntax based on the edior i'm using

Comment: The editor doesn't determine syntax. Double slashes are not valid in CSS.

Comment: where am i using double slashes, it's single slashes only /*  */

Comment: See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75988946/revisions) (also linked above) and the [source of your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8b9b7a34-3f28-4d02-b17f-28e44c121dcc/view-source). I made the correction so your snippet would run properly in the demo and others could copy it to answers.

Comment: Oh got it now! Thanks a lot for the edit, i was confused because it looked the same to me. It's not a excuse but i am a nub here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to make CSS rules fall higher in specificity rank. An easy one is to prepend `body`, which just adds another component to the selector and therefore increases specificity. Avoid using `!important` as it makes future work more difficult.

```css
body h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5; /* overridden from 1.2 */
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 900; /* overridden from 500 */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1>Montserrat black 900 font weight</h1>
```